# Python timer in if else statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a timer that starts when a condition for an if statement is met and then stops and returns the duration when elif condition is met, is this possible?

The purpose of the application is to send a true or false value to AWS IoT from an Android application. The Python script is subscribed to AWS and receives the value and uses it to determine whether the led should be on or off.

The code I have:

```
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import logging
import time
from time import sleep
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import getopt
import grovepi

msgpay = None

# Custom MQTT message callback
def customCallback(client, userdata, message):
    print("Received a new message: ")
    print(message.payload)
    print("from topic: ")
    print(message.topic)
    print("--------------\n\n")
    global msgpay
    msgpay = message.payload
   led = 5
   grovepi.pinMode(led, "OUTPUT")
   start_time = timer()
   if msgpay == "true":
       print("turning on")
       grovepi.digitalWrite(led, 1)
       #time.sleep(3)
   elif msgpay == "false":
       print("turning off")
       grovepi.digitalWrite(led, 0)
       duration = timer() - start_time
       print duration
```

Any help how to go about this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're aksing if its possible, but did you try yourself ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but can't get it to work the way I want.

Comment: Do you get an error ? What do you mean by "not the way I want" ?

Comment: Is this you full code? It looks like you are using some extra libraries like `grovepi` (which are not included in your code). Is your code inside a `loop()` function like in Arduino? Otherwise you will need a loop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).
You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem.
You should also read [Ask].

Comment: No sorry this is only a snippet from a larger script. The script runs fine with no errors, it's just that I want to time the duration from when the led is turned on to when it is turned off but can only get it to run in either the "if" or the "elif", returning a duration of less than a second.

Comment: Yea, sorry I'm quite new to this, I will read up on asking questions properly. The full script is on a Raspberry Pi so it's not easy for me to get it onto my laptop.

Comment: It's not easy to get the script on your laptop from a raspberry? just connect to the raspberry by ssh. Also if this is not your full code we will be unable to help. If you can only get into the if or the elif it means that the condition doesn't change, so there's no actual time to measure.

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully this is clearer to understand.